# What do chazal mean when they guarantee someone Olam Habah?

Tags: olam-haba-world-to-come

What does it mean when the Gemara guarantees a person  Olam Habah for doing a certain deed (for example saying Ashrei three times a day)? How is it different from any other good deed that one does?

Comment: Great question. I also wonder whether the guarantee still applies if the person's other behavior is lacking. I would guess not, but where is the provision for that?

Comment: Is there two questions? What does mean a "guarantee" to Olam Haba? What is the special property of some deeds as saying Ashrei three times a day, which links them to Olam Haba. Both questions are excellent and I am interested to read an answerr.

Answer (score 1):

I heard a tape of Rabbi Avigdor Miller once where he says whenever you hear such things there's always a catch (I think he said "fine print"). For example, regarding Ashrei he says it means you live what it says not just recite it.

As to why it is different perhaps because these things encompass most of the Torah.

Answer (score 0):

Hazal say things by way of **stressing** the importance of deeds one might be lax about. That is a general principle, like the Torah itself promisses a great reward specifically for certain commandments by way of encouragement.